# Prob. 1, Sec. 6.3, in Bartle & Sherbert's INTRO TO REAL ANALYSIS, 4th ed: If $g\to 0$ and $\lim f/g$ exists, then $f \to 0$. Do we need continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, proof-verification, derivatives

Here is Prob. 1, Sec. 6.3, in the book *Introduction to Real Analysis* by Robert G. Bartle & Donald R. Sherbert, 4th edition:

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a, b]$, differentiable on $(a, b)$, that $c \in [a, b]$ and $g(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in [a, b]$, $x \neq c$. Let $A \colon= \lim_{x\to c} f$ and $B \colon= \lim_{x\to c} g$. If $B = 0$, and if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)/g(x)$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$, show that we must have $A=0$. [ *Hint*: $f(x) = \big\{ f(x) / g(x) \big\} g(x)$.]

My Attempt:

> As $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = A$ and as $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$, let us put $l \colon= \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. Then $l \in \mathbb{R}$ and since $g(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ such that $x \neq c$, therefore we have 
>   $$ f(x) = \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} g(x) $$
>   for all $x \in [a, b]$ such that $x \neq c$, and hence by Theorem 4.24 in Bartle & Sherbert, 4th edition, we must also have 
>   $$ \lim_{x \to c} f(x) =  \lim_{x \to c} \left[ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} g(x) \right] = \left[ \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right] \lim_{x \to c} g(x) = l \times 0 = 0. $$

Is this proof correct and satisfactory enough for the level of rigor required by Bartle & Sherbert?

If so, then my question is, in our hypothesis do we really need the functions $f$ and $g$ to be continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$ for the conclusion to hold?

If not, then where am I lacking?

Comment: It looks fine to me, in particular, the statement has indeed useless assumptions.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the level of rigor required by Bartle & Sherbert"?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom by this I mean the level of rigor at which Bartle & Sherbert discusses the subject matter.

Comment: Well Bartle and Sherbert "requires" a certain level of rigor because it aims to teach analysis to an audience with no such background.  Who exactly is the audience for your proof?

Comment: The reason I ask is that in the posts that I have seen from you over the past few years, it seems as though you put a lot of effort in making sure that you have technically accounted for all logical steps in the proof while putting no effort into making the proof an efficient and understandable progression of ideas.  This seems like an odd choice to me.