# Prob. 2, Sec. 6.3, in Bartle & Sherbert's INTRO TO REAL ANALYSIS, 4th ed: If $f\to A>0$, $g>0$, and $g\to 0$, then $f/g\to +\infty$; ...

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

Here is Prob. 1, Sec. 6.3, in the book *Introduction to Real Analysis* by Robert G. Bartle & Donald R. Sherbert, 4th edition:

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a, b]$, differentiable on $(a, b)$, that $c \in [a, b]$ and $g(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in [a, b]$, $x \neq c$. Let $A \colon= \lim_{x\to c} f$ and $B \colon= \lim_{x\to c} g$. If $B = 0$, and if $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)/g(x)$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$, show that we must have $A=0$. [ *Hint*: $f(x) = \big\{ f(x) / g(x) \big\} g(x)$.]

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3458408/prob-1-sec-6-3-in-bartle-sherberts-intro-to-real-analysis-4th-ed-if-g) is my Math SE post on this problem.

And, here is Prob. 2, Sec. 6,3:

> In addition to the suppositions of the preceding exercise, let $g(x) > 0$ for $x \in [a, b]$, $x \neq c$. If $A > 0$ and $B = 0$, prove that we must have $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)/g(x) = \infty$. If $A < 0$ and $B = 0$, prove that we must have $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)/ g(x) = -\infty$.

My Attempt:

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are real-valued functions defined on the closed interval $[a, b]$ and that $c \in [a, b]$ is such that
>
> (i) $g(x) > 0$ for $x \in [a, b]$ such that $x \neq c$,
>
> (ii) $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$, and
>
> (iii) $\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = 0$.
>
> Let us put $A \colon= \lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ and $B \colon= \lim_{x \to c} g(x)$. Then $B = 0$ of course.
>
> We study the following two cases according as $A> 0$ or $A < 0$.
>
> Case 1. First suppose that $A > 0$.
>
> Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary. Then as $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = A$, so there exists a real number $\delta_1 > 0$ and depending on $A > 0$ such that 
>   $$ \big\lvert  f(x) - A \big\rvert  < \frac{A}{2} $$
>   for all $x \in [a, b]$ such that $0 < \big\lvert x-c \big\rvert < \delta_1$. Therefore we have 
>   $$ f(x) > \frac{A}{2} > 0 \tag{1} $$
>   for all $x \in [a, b]$ such that $0 < \big\lvert x-c \big\rvert < \delta_1$.
>
> Now as $\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = 0$, and as 
>   $$ \frac{A}{2 \big( \lvert \alpha \rvert + 1 \big) } > 0, $$ 
>   so there exists a real number $\delta_2 > 0$ and depending on $\alpha$ (and $A$) such that 
>   $$ 0 < g(x) =  \big\lvert g(x)  \big\rvert = \big\lvert g(x) - 0 \big\rvert < \frac{A}{2 \big( \lvert \alpha \rvert + 1 \big) } $$
>   for all $x \in [a, b]$ such that $0 < \lvert x-c \rvert < \delta_2$. Therefore we must also have 
>   $$ \frac{1}{g(x)} > \frac{ 2 \big( \lvert \alpha \rvert + 1 \big) }{A} \tag{2} $$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ such that $0 < \lvert x-c \rvert < \delta_2$.
>
> Let us put $\delta \colon= \min \left\{ \delta_1, \delta_2 \right\}$. Then $\delta > 0$ since both $\delta_1 > 0$ and $\delta_2 > 0$.
>
> Then from (1) and (2) above, we can conclude that for all $x \in [a, b]$ such that $0 < \lvert x-c \rvert < \delta$, we must have
>   $$ \frac{ f(x) }{ g(x) } = f(x) \frac{1}{g(x)} > \frac{A}{2} \frac{ 2 \big( \lvert \alpha \rvert + 1 \big) }{A} = \lvert \alpha \rvert + 1 > \lvert \alpha \rvert \geq \alpha. $$
>
> Thus we have shown that, corresponding to any given real number $\alpha$, there exists a real number $\delta > 0$ and depending on $\alpha$ such that 
>   $$ \frac{ f(x) }{ g(x) } > \alpha $$
>   for all $x \in [a, b]$ such that $0 < \lvert x-c \rvert < \delta$.
>
> Therefore by virtue of Definition 4.3.5 (i) in Bartle & Sherbert, 4th edition, we conclude that 
>   $$ \lim_{x \to c} \frac{ f(x) }{ g(x) } = +\infty. $$
>
> Case 2. Now suppose that $A < 0$.
>
> Let us choose an arbitrary real number $\beta$. Then as $A< 0$, so $-A>0$, and there exists a real number $\delta_1 > 0$ and depending on $A$ such that 
>   $$ \big\lvert f(x) - A \big\rvert < \frac{-A}{2} $$
>   and so 
>   $$ f(x) < \frac{A}{2} < 0 \tag{3} $$
>   for all $x \in [a, b]$ such that $0 < \lvert x-c \rvert < \delta_1$.
>
> Also there exists a real number $\delta_2 > 0$ and depending on $\beta$ (and also on $A$) such that 
>   $$ 0 < g(x) = \big\lvert g(x) \big\rvert = \big\lvert g(x) - 0 \big\rvert < \frac{ A }{ -2 \big( \lvert \beta \rvert + 1 \big) } $$
>   and so 
>   $$ \frac{1}{g(x) } > \frac{-2 \big( \lvert \beta \rvert + 1 \big)  }{ A } > 0 \tag{4} $$
>   for all $x \in [a, b]$ satisfying $0 < \lvert x-c \rvert < \delta_2$.
>
> Then, for all $x \in [a, b]$ for which $0 < \lvert x-c \rvert < \min\left\{ \delta_1, \delta_2 \right\}$, we also have 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>  \frac{ f(x) }{ g(x) } &= f(x) \frac{1}{g(x)} \\
> &< f(x) \left( \frac{-2 \big( \lvert \beta \rvert + 1 \big)  }{ A } \right) \qquad  [ \mbox{because of (4) and the fact from (3) that $f(x) < 0$} ]\\
> &< \frac{A}{2} \left(  \frac{-2 \big( \lvert \beta \rvert + 1 \big)  }{ A } \right) \qquad [ \mbox{ Refer to (3) and (4) above again. } ] \\
> &= - \lvert \beta \rvert - 1  \\
> &< -\lvert \beta \vert \\
> &\leq \beta. 
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> Since $\beta$ was an arbitrarily chosen real number, it follows from Definition 4.3.5 (ii) that 
>   $$ \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = -\infty. $$

Is this proof correct and rigorous enough for Bartle & Sherbert? If so, then is there any necessity for the assumptions of continuity of $f$ and $g$ on $[a, b]$ and differentiability of these functions on $(a, b)$?

Or, what is missing in my proof?

Last but not least, do we really need to assume the differentiability of functions $f$ and $g$ on $(a, b)$? or the continuity of functions $f$ and $g$ on $[a, b]$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your proof is technically correct.  However, in order to make your proofs readable, you should consider making them more concise.  Here are some minor improvements.

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are real-valued functions defined on the closed interval $[a, b]$ and that $c \in [a, b]$ is such that
>
> (i) $g(x) > 0$ for $x \in [a, b]$ such that $x \neq c$,
>
> (ii) $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$, and
>
> (iii) $\lim_{x \to c} g(x) = 0$.
>
> Let us put $A \colon= \lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ and $B \colon= \lim_{x \to c} g(x)$. Then $B = 0$ of course.

This is your weakened version of the assumptions in the problem statement, and perhaps you should make it clearer that this is the case.  Otherwise, so far so good.

> We study the following two cases according as $A> 0$ or $A < 0$.
>
> Case 1. First suppose that $A > 0$.
>
> Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ be arbitrary.

It suffices to take $\alpha>0$, and this would get rid of the absolute values later. I would also include why we care about the $\alpha$, something like "we want to find a $\delta$ such that $|x-c|<\delta$ implies that $f(x)/g(x) > \alpha$".

An edited version of the remainder of your case 1 proof:

> Then as $\lim_{x \to c} f(x) = A$, there exists a real number $\delta_1 > 0$ such that 
>   $\big\lvert  f(x) - A \big\rvert  < \frac{A}{2}$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ such that $0 < \big\lvert x-c \big\rvert < \delta_1$. For all such $x$, we have 
>   $$ f(x) > \frac{A}{2} > 0. \tag{1} $$
>
> Moreover, since $\lim_{x \to c}g(x) = 0$, there exists a real number $\delta_2 > 0$ such that 
>   $
> 0 < g(x) < \frac{A}{2(\lvert \alpha \rvert + 1)} 
> $
>   for all $x \in [a, b]$ such that $0 < \lvert x-c \rvert < \delta_2$. Therefore we must also have 
>   $$ \frac{1}{g(x)} > \frac{ 2 \big( \lvert \alpha \rvert + 1 \big) }{A} \tag{2} $$ for all $x \in [a, b]$ such that $0 < \lvert x-c \rvert < \delta_2$.
>
> Let $\delta \colon= \min \left\{ \delta_1, \delta_2 \right\}$. From (1) and (2) above, we can conclude that for all $x \in [a, b]$ such that $0 < \lvert x-c \rvert < \delta$, we must have
>   $$ \frac{ f(x) }{ g(x) } = f(x) \frac{1}{g(x)} > \frac{A}{2} \frac{ 2 \big( \lvert \alpha \rvert + 1 \big) }{A} = \lvert \alpha \rvert + 1 > \lvert \alpha \rvert \geq \alpha. $$
>
> Thus we have shown that, corresponding to any given real number $\alpha$, there exists a real number $\delta > 0$ and depending on $\alpha$ such that 
>   $$ \frac{ f(x) }{ g(x) } > \alpha $$
>   for all $x \in [a, b]$ such that $0 < \lvert x-c \rvert < \delta$. Therefore we conclude that 
>   $$ \lim_{x \to c} \frac{ f(x) }{ g(x) } = +\infty $$
>   as was desired.

Now, case 2 can be greatly abbreviated: if we consider the function $h(x):=-f(x)$, then we can simply apply your proof for case 1 to deduce that $h(x)/g(x) \to +\infty$, from which the desired conclusion follows.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that neither continuity nor differentiability is needed for these results.

I haven't read through your proof carefully, but it sure looks correct to me, and certainly rigorous enough for B&J (especially given that they're throwing in unnecessary assumptions!)

I did notice one thing: if you have proved it for $A>0,$ then you can obtain a quick proof for $A<0$: Suppose we have the result for $A>0.$ If now $A<0,$ then $\lim_{x\to c} -f(x) = -A>0.$ Hence $\lim_{x\to c} -f(x)/g(x) = \infty.$ Therefore $\lim_{x\to c} -[-f(x)/g(x)] =-\infty.$ Since $-[-f(x)/g(x)]=f(x)/g(x),$ we're done.